# Is it important to clear buckets for performance reasons?

Tags: couchbase

My app keeps inserting documents to buckets.
It never deletes them, assuming that the data will be rotated once it reaches the max ram limit assigned to the bucket.

But what effect does full buckets have on speed of data retrieval?
Do I need to make sure documents are deleted once they are no longer needed to maintain performance?
Is there a difference in this aspect between Ephermal and Couchbase buckets?

Answer (score 0):

> assuming that the data will be rotated once it reaches the max ram limit assigned to the bucket

That's quite an assumption. You should test it before proceeding. I wouldn't be the least bit surprised if the database simply stopped accepting new documents once it hit its limits.

Comment: My Ephermal type buckets are configured with NRU ejection.
So the data will be rotated.
The question is how would a memory bucket with 0.5GB of data would perform as opposed to 5mb of data..

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question and I would recommend reading over the Couchbase Server documentation. Here is a quick-ish TL;DR:

There are three type of [buckets](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/learn/buckets-memory-and-storage/buckets.html) in Couchbase Server each one behave differently when they get full.

**Couchbase Bucket**

A Couchbase Bucket writes the documents to disk and also caches them in memory. It has two different ejection modes; *Value-only* and *Full*. Value-only mode removes just the value of the document from memory where full can remove both the value and the metadata about the document from memory. This means that a Couchbase bucket configured with value-only ejection can get full and stop accepting writes, where this can't happen with full eject. If a Document is not in memory it will be fetched from disk which is slower.

**Ephemeral Bucket**

Ephemeral bucket store the documents only in memory and can be seen as a replacement for memcached buckets. The way it behaves when the bucket gets full can be controlled, there are two modes. *No ejection* - no data is eject and instead new writes are reject. In this case it's up to the application to delete data. *NRU ejection* data is deleted base on not recently used algorithm. In both cases there will not be a drop in performance as the bucket gets full from the Couchbase Server view point.From the application stand point there might be a performance hit as it has to fetch the data from another source.

**Memcached Bucket**

In this case when the bucket is full, memcached buckets behave just like an Ephemeral bucket with NRU ejection. Ephemeral buckets have a number of improvements over memcached buckets and should be used instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have read that document.
But I see no supporting evidence of: "In both cases there will not be a drop in performance" in the Couchbase docs...